# Regarding a constant in verilog

Tags: verilog

I was going through a piece of verilog code and came accross the following

```
abet_val<=strt?{{12 -1{1'b0}}, write_rly}:{{12 -1{1'b0}}, 1'b1};
```

what does the stuff inside the curly braces "{}" mean?
Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102746/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-verilog

Comment: ...and note that '12-1' is evaluated as an expression in both places, so it's '11'.

Answer (score 0):

it is a mux between `{11'b0}, write_rly`  and `12'b1` . when strt is a one you pick the first option and when it is a zero you get the second output

{} these are the concatenation operator meaning you combine them to make one number