# Verilog binary addition

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Binary addition on `A` and `B` and outputs it along with proper carry bit. I'm not sure how to implement the carry bit

`A` and `B` are 4 bit inputs

`C` is 1 bit output that is used for the carry bit

```
module addop(C , O , A , B);
   input [3:0] A;
   input [3:0] B;
   output [3:0] O;
   output       C;

   assign C1 = A[0] + B[0];
   assign C2 = A[0] + B[1];
endmodule
```

Answer (score 6):

You may want to use a concatenation operator `{}` here.

```
module addop(C, O, A, B);
   input [3:0] A;
   input [3:0] B;
   output [3:0] O;
   output       C;

   assign {C, O} = A + B;
endmodule
```

Your synthesis tool will be responsible in converting them
into logic gates.

See this question which is related to concatenation:

[What do curly braces mean in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102746/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-verilog)