# What is the correct syntax for assigning one value to multiple variables in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am writing a 64-bit adder module, and my inputs are a,b,cin and my outputs are sum and carry.
I want to use a continuous assignment, and so I wrote `assign sum = (a + b);` before my end module.
In order to also assign this value to my carry, would `assign sum,carry = (a + b);`  be the correct syntax? I also saw online that it should include curly brackets  `assign {sum, carry} = (a + b);` but it was not explicitly stated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curly braces in verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894112/curly-braces-in-verilog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should include curly brackets.

```
{  ,  ,  }
```

This is the *concatenation operator* in Verilog. So,

```
assign {carry,sum} = (a + b);
```

Is what you want. (Note that in Verilog the LSB is always on the right hand side, so the carry needs to be on the left.)