# What does this curly braces mean in Systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I am starting to learn **SystemVerilog**. I am stuck with a priority encoder and can't get this part :

```
priority if (encoder_in == {{14{1'bx}},1'b1,{1{1'b0}}})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do curly braces mean in Verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102746/what-do-curly-braces-mean-in-verilog)

Answer (score 2):

this is actually a concatenation of 3 constants.

```
{  {14{1'bx}}, 1'b1, {1{1'b0}}  }
1--^^^^^^^^^^ 
2--------------^^^^
3--------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

1. is a replication operator and it generates a 14-bits of 'x'.
2. is a one-bit 1
3. is a replication operator with a single repetition. I have no idea why it is used this way.

The following would be an equivalent expression:

```
{{14{1'bx}}, 1'b1, 1'b0}
```

or  this

```
{{14{1'bx}}, 2'b10}
```

or this:

```
 16'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx10
```

Next, `priority` is a system verilog modifier which could be applied to an `if` or a `case` operators. Read about `unique` end `priority` modifiers in system verilog.